# Getting time of form submission in Django

Tags: django

What is the command to find the date/time of a post/get submission in django? For example, someone is submitting an email, and I want to be able to pull --

Email@example.com   -     time_submitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches:

First you could modify the view to create a field and add it to the form when you save the response.  Something like:

```
if form.is_valid() :
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    ... save it, print it, whatever...
```

The better way is to handle it at model level, and just have a field for it.

> created_at    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Now when you save the input to your DB, you've got creation time of when the save() method was called.

Comment: The submitted form might not create a new table row, or even be backed by a model database model, for that matter.  When *possible*, it is somewhat cleaner.

Comment: Yes, that is why I gave the first option... send the value somewhere.  If one wanted to be creative you would still use a Model with a subclass method like "write to CSV"...

Answer (score 8):

If you mean when you're processing the form in the view, then why not just use datetime.datetime.now() at any point in the view? That'll be milliseconds after the user pressed Submit

Comment: Clean and simple approach, easy to implement, easy to see what's going on. This is the best approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Http get/post operations don't send the time to the server so as stevejalim mentions you can get the a timestamp in your server side code.  Alternatively, you can pass an additional parameter representing the time the user clicked/submitted the page.  You would set the parameter using javascript:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "timestamp").val(new Date().getTime());
    $('#form1').append($(input));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This relies on the client's clock being set correctly, which isn't necessarily a given.

Comment: +1 It also leaves it open to tampering, which may not be great if you're, say, trying to log times of important actions